# Linearization of a tensor?

Tags: proof-verification, differential-geometry

Suppose that $(M,g)$ is a Riemannain manifold and $\nabla$ denotes its Levi-Civita connection. Define a‎ $(0,2)‎$ tensor field $\pi$ by‎
$$‎\pi (X,Y)=(‎\nabla_X \omega‎)(Y)-\omega (X)\omega (Y)+‎\dfrac{1}{2}‎\omega (‎U‎)‎g(X,Y)‎‎$$
where $\omega$ is an 1-form on $(M,g)$ and $U$ is its equivalent vector field, in fact for all $X\in \mathcal{X}(M)$
$$\omega (X)=g(X,U).$$
Suppose $g(t)=g+ts$ and $\omega (t)=\omega +t\delta$, I want to linearize $|\pi |^2$. ‎By means of a local coordinate system on $M$ with local frame $\partial_i$‎, ‎set $‎\pi ‎(\partial_i,\partial_j)=‎\pi‎_{ij}$‎. ‎consequently‎,
‎$$
‎\pi_{ij}=‎\nabla_i ‎\omega‎_j ‎-\omega_i ‎\omega_j ‎+‎\dfrac{1}{2}g_‎{‎ij} ‎|\omega|^2‎
‎$$
‎where,‎‎‎ $‎\omega‎(\partial_i)=\omega_i$. ‎We ‎have‎
$$‎|\pi |^2=g^{ij}\pi_‎{‎ij}=\mathrm{div}(\omega) ‎‎+‎(‎‎\dfrac{n}{2}-1)|\omega |^2 ‎‎.‎$$‎‎
Consequently,‎
‎$$
(|\pi (t) ‎‎|^2 )'(0)=‎<‎‎‎d ‎\omega +(‎‎\dfrac{n}{2}-1)\omega\otimes \omega‎,‎-‎s>+<g ,d\delta +(n-2)\omega\otimes \delta>.‎
‎$$

> Is my result correct?